# How do I write a function that prints counts of values in an array, taking the array as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, arrays, parameters, counting, coin-flipping

Starting with the below program that creates an array of coin flips, I have to add a function that prints out the total number of heads and total number of tails flipped.  The function must take the array of flips as a parameter.

This is the given program:

```
var NUM_FLIPS = 100;

function start(){
    var flips = flipCoins();
    printArray(flips);
    countHeadsAndTails();
}

// This function should flip a coin NUM_FLIPS
// times, and add the result to an array. We
// return the result to the caller.
function flipCoins(){
    var flips = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < NUM_FLIPS; i++){
        if(Randomizer.nextBoolean()){
            flips.push("Heads");
        }else{
            flips.push("Tails");
        }
    }
    return flips;
}

function printArray(arr){
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        println(i + ": " + arr[i]);
    }
}
```

And I need to write this function:

```
function countHeadsAndTails(flips) {
    //Write the program here
}
```

This is what I have so far, but the function does not work as expected. I am stuck on what to put in the `if` statement.

```
function countHeadsAndTails(flips) {        
    var headCount = 0;
    var tailCount = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < NUM_FLIPS; i++) {
        if (i == "Heads") {
            headCount += 1;
        }else {
            tailCount += 1;
        }
    }

    println("Total Heads: " + headCount);
    println("Total Tails: " + tailCount);
}
```

The program randomly flips heads or tails 100 times and prints out the results, but the counter does not work and I get this:

```
Total Heads: 100
Total Tails: 0
```

Comment: `i == "Heads"` clearly won't work, because you've declared `i` as a number (`for (var i = 0...`)). What type is `flips`, and how is it accessed in the code that prints its contents?

Comment: Also use `headCount++` instead of `headCount += 1`

Comment: You need to pass the array to the counting function. It should be `countHeadsAndTails(flips);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `if (i == "Heads") {` doesn't work is because `i` is the current index (a number) and you're comparing it to a string `"Heads"`. I suspect what you want is `if (flips[i] == "Heads") {`. Basically using the index `i` to grab the `i`th element in the array and comparing that with `"Heads"`.

Also the parameter `flips` is not being passed to `countHeadsAndTails()` in the `start()` function. Looks like that might be a problem with the provided problem itself. I assume the `countHeadsAndTails` stub function they provided already had the `flips` parameter?

Comment: Why are you doing the homework instead of letting the poster figure it out? Sort of defeats the purpose of the assignment. Don't we have enough copy/paste programmers?  I redo enough work done by them.

Comment: You've got a point but the poster did narrow it down to 1 line of code she's stuck on. Seems pretty reasonably to me. Would you prefer I explain why it doesn't work and leave it at that?

Comment: @KenWhite The purpose of this site is to show programmers where they went wrong and how to fix it. We complain when they don't provide their code, but this one did. What's wrong with that?

Comment: I already tried if (flips[i] == "Heads") { but I get the error message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.

Comment: Yes. :-) The poster was given the assignment so that they would do the work to complete it. Teachers use it to assess the understanding of the course material and teach additional skills (hopefully, something other than *post on SO and get someone else to do it for you*).

Comment: @Barmar: Didn't say there was anything wrong with the post. Was just suggesting that an answer that offered instruction and guidance rather than copy/paste code would have been better IMO. Note I did not downvote?

Comment: But @KenWhite, then the teacher should also dis-allow the students from asking these questions on SO, and put it in the book of "cheating". The answer provided here is exactly how SO is instended :/ Don't get me wrong, I wholeheartedly agree with you, but if anything, it's the OP doing something wrong, not Rocky.

Comment: @Freddy: I highly doubt any teacher is saying *Feel free to see if you can get someone at SO to do it for you.* Wow. Lots of *lets teach copy/paste programming* supporters here in this comment thread. I find I learn more if I work to figure things out myself, and a little guidance teaches me more than just having someone else do it for me. Guess I'm old school.

Comment: @KenWhite I never said that? lol... Talk about twisting my words to the complete opposite. Haha. I'm just like you, and I agree completely, only times I ask a question is the times I truly have no clue what to do and are lost in all ways. But like I stated earlier, if anything, it's the OP doing something wrong here, not Rocky.

Comment: @EmilyJ. It sounds like you didn't pass the array containing the flips to the counting function.

Comment: @EmilyJ. I think Barmar is correct though given the context it seems like that might be an issue with the problem they provided to you rather than your mistake.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you!!! I didn't notice that and I changed it to `countHeadsAndTails(flips);` and now it works!